# Collecting and storing HTML elements

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

How do i collect the value of a p-tag and store it in vue?

```
<p id="idNum">{{lesson._id}}</p>
```

Comment: The p-tag is getting the lesson from a database, I'm trying to get the value store it in a Vue object

Answer (score -1):

```
const value = document.querySelector('p#idNum').textContent
```

Comment: It's returns empty If I store it in a global variable

Answer (score -1):

**Working Demo :**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
        lesson: {
            _id: 123
        },
      paragraphValue: ''
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.paragraphValue = document.getElementById('idNum').innerHTML;
    console.log(this.paragraphValue);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p id="idNum">{{ lesson._id }}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

use ref instead of id and you can call it like `console.log(refs["idNum"])`

```
<p ref="idNum">{{lesson._id}}</p>
```

Do not forget to `import ref from vue`